# How are currency exchange rates on yahoo finance computed?

Tags: currency, yahoofinance

I've been looking for the metadata about how the exchange rates on yahoo finance computed, but I cant find anything on the website.
Please kindly help me, thank you.

This is the example USDIDR=X:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to the finance data disclaimer (https://help.yahoo.com/kb/exchanges-data-providers-yahoo-finance-sln2310.html) the source for fx rates is the ICE data service.

Comment: They in turn [do](https://www.theice.com/data-services/derivatives/foreign-exchange) what everyone else does with OTC traded assets. Get it from a list of marker makers (brokers, banks etc).